# Winsock TCP recv() hangs for 5 seconds

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, delay, winsock, recv

I have a native Visual C++ application which acts as a socket server: it accepts incoming TCP connections, and it reads some data from those sockets.
Once a new TCP connection is received / accepted by the server, a new thread is spawn, and all reads (i.e., calls to recv()) on that connected socket happen in that separate thread. All communication is done according to a well-defined standard application-level protocol, implemented by several clients by different developers/vendors. Hence, my server application is able to communicate with clients by different developers/vendors, as long as they comply with this well-defined application-level protocol.

Now, my server application works fine with 99.9% of the client applications. Nevertheless, I am experiencing strange delays with just a few clients.

In particular, with these "problematic" clients, once the client connection has been accepted by my server application, the recv() calls in my dedicated "receiver" thread hang for exactly 5 seconds before returning, even though data shall be available, since the client has already completed several send() calls.

The clients connecting to my server application run on hosts residing on the same LAN as the host upon which my server application runs.

Please notice the following facts:

1 - With these specific "problematic" clients, **ALL** recv() calls in my server application hang for 5 seconds before returning.

2 - My server application works fine (i.e., recv() show no relevant delays) with other clients (actually, the vast majority of them).

3 - On the other side, those "problematic" clients seem to work fine (i.e., no particular delays) with other third-party server applications implementing the same application-level protocol as my own server application. Some of those third-party server applications are open source: I've inspected the source code of those third-party server applications, but I could not find any relevant difference in their implementation which could apparently justify the 5-seconds delay that I am experiencing in my server application.

I realize that I described the issue in quite generic terms, but maybe this "5 exact seconds" delay may tell something to some TCP/IP expert...

I would really appreciate any hint or suggestion to troubleshoot this problem.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Have you confirmed this with packet capture (e.g. Wireshark).  Specifically I would verify that data has already been received, and no retransmits were needed?  Completion of `send()` calls doesn't mean much, you could have Nagle turned on, or packets could be dropped in the network.

Comment: smells like a timeout... have you set the socket to be non-blocking?

Comment: So, to be clear, it's a consistent set of client machines that exhibit this problem?

Comment: Hi all, and thanks for your feedback.
I haven't been able to inspect the situation with Wireshark yet: testing these "problematic" clients is a bit difficult, since these TCP clients are actually medical devices working at a customer facility. It is not so easy to "debug" the issue there and/or to make tests and stop the customer's operations. I will try using Wireshark there as soon as possible.

However, as per point 3. in my original post, the strange thing is that if I replace my server app with a 3rd party server app implementing the same application-level protocol, there are no delays.

Comment: My sockets are blocking, since this is what I require. However, with some "rare" clients, each recv() blocks for exactly 5 seconds before returning. This is abnormal, and different from how other 3rd party server applications (implementing the same application-level protocol) behave, reading the same amount of data as my own application.

Comment: Yes, this problem only happens with a few client machines (which are medical devices, in this case), having a particular implementation of the client software.
One may argue that it may be a client software issue, but once again, the same clients work fine if I replace my own server application with a 3rd party server application implementing the same application-level protocol. It may look like a problem of socket options, or similar, but checking the source code of these 3rd party applications it looks like we set the same socket options, buffer sizes, etc...

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `recv`? When it returns after exactly five seconds, *what* does it return?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a timeout so that it won't delay for more than x seconds, look into using the function [select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The server you are connecting to is send a Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100 in its HTTP output header, which recv() is respecting

Adding

> Connection: close

To their output header will solve your delay. I have not idea if recv() can be made to ignore the keep-alive directive.